# asp.net - auto checked the radiobutton if the same database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to have my `radiobutton` to be automatically be `checked` if the value in my database matches his. here is like this.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="serviceable" GroupName="inputStatus" runat="server" Text="Serviceable" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="unserviceable" GroupName="inputStatus" runat="server" Text="Unserviceable" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="fordisposal" GroupName="inputStatus" runat="server" Text="For disposal" />
```

In my back code I am calling it like this.

```
   status = rdr["asset_status"].ToString();
```

then im thinking about doing an `if` or maybe `javascript` but I am not fond of using Javascript.. Sooo how can I use the variable `status` to define whether what `radiobutton` will be checked? Thank you

Comment: what does asset_status returns?

Comment: the string in the `Text=` exactly in the radio button as ease

Answer (score 1):

you can use switch statement which are fast in performance than condition

```
string check = "For disposal";
 switch (check)
         {
                        case "Serviceable":
                            serviceable.Checked = true;
                            break; /* optional */
                        case "Unserviceable":
                            unserviceable.Checked = true;
                            break; /* optional */
                        case "For disposal":
                            fordisposal.Checked = true;
                            break; /* optional */


           }
```

it will check the `case` if it matches it will set that radio button to `true` and it will work on both `webforms` and `winforms`

Answer (score 0):

According to your code imagine you want to check your radiobutton with id `serviceable` in some conditions of status value.

```
 if(status=="somevalue")
 {
    serviceable.Checked = true;
 }
```

If your RadioButton ID exactly matchs your status you can check your radio according to status text without even using if statement.

```
 (this.FindControl(status.ToLower()) as RadioButton).Checked = true;
```

But if your radiobutton text exactly matchs your status I suggest you to use `RadioButtonList` and then you can use the following code snippet to select radiobuttons those text matchs exactly status.

```
RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = RadioButtonList1.Items.IndexOf(RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByText(status));
```

Comment: I'm using this waybaaack in `winforms` don't know why i didn't think of it. But it worked.

Comment: If it matchs exactly then i suggest you to use RadioButtonList for convenience.

Comment: So that I can elimante the if condition? and can you do the `RadioButtonList1` as like my code in the question? Im wondering if GroupName will work there

Comment: RadioButtonList works like Listbox or DropdownList. You must set Datasource property for that. And also DataValueField and DataTextField

Comment: You can also use that code snippet if your radiobutton id exactly matchs your status. `(this.FindControl(status.ToLower()) as RadioButton).Checked = true;`   Check my answer again i edited that.

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but it said that ListItem is not a know element. Maybe because I'm using VS2012 so I did what you first suggested. Thank you